# write calculation code before this() function

Tags: scala

could any one tell me why I could not write calculation code before this() function in scala class?

```
    //compile pass
     class A(a:Int) {
        def this() = {this(3)}
     }

     //compile error
     class A(a:Int) {
        def this() = {
          val tmp = 3 //or other complex calculations( error: 'this' expected but 'val' found.)
          this(tmp)
        }
     }
```

Comment: Generally you don't write constructors in scala. Write `apply` methods in the companion object instead.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot since you must call another constructor as the first thing in an auxiliary constructor. What you can do instead is use a block expression as argument:

```
class A(a:Int) {
  def this() = this({
    val tmp = 3
    tmp
  })
}
```

Comment: because if it weren't designed it would likely be even worse. On the bright side, you'd never have gotten to use it